# Android AudioRecord send over RTP

Tags: android, rtp, pcm, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

**Background**

I am creating a VoIP app. I know that there are plenty of ones out already, but I have my reasons. Due to commercial implications I cannot just fork SipDroid, although it is a quality app. This app is aimed at Level 10 Gingerbread 2.3.3.

**Problem**

I have created a simple Activity which creates an AudioRecord instance, and then begins a loop:

```
int timestamp = 0;
int seqNr = 12;
while(true) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int num = recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    try {
        byte[] pcm = new byte[bufferSize];
        //
        // presumably here I convert the byte[] from PCM into G711??
        //
        RTPStream.Write(pcm,seqNr,timestamp);
        timestamp += num;
        seqNr++;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Question**

How do I turn the PCM 44KHz 16bit Mono `byte[]`'s into G711u/a `byte[]`'s??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioGroup is available internally. That is what Native SipAudioCall is using. There is a a way to use internal API. Knowing that the class will be available in API 12. You should use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `AudioStram` instead. Set codec via `setCodec(AudioCodec)` and acquire audio via `AudioGroup`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I am building this for Gingerbread - AudioGroup is API Level 14 onwards.

Comment: Huh? As I see it AudioGroup is API 12: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioGroup.html